# heatmap in local html don't work on IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I'm playing with heatmap of Google Maps. We have a nice demo [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap?hl=es). In this page we have all HTML and JavaScript code necessary to show this heatmap.

If I create a local HTML web page with this code and I try to show it into IE browser, it don't show any more that a message "Internet Explorer blocked this site to avoid execute scripts or ActiveX controls on your computer" (translated from spanish, sorry for bad translation).

If I put this HTML file into my web space, work perfectly.

The question is, why and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of IE are you using and what level is your security settings set at in your Internet Options?

Comment: The _"why"_ part of this question is because IE is viewing your script as a security threat, so by default, it's not trusting it to execute. This is indeed a good thing. The _"how"_ involves going into the _"Tools > Internet Options > Security (tab)"_ section of IE and setting custom rules to allow your script to run. I ***strongly advise against*** allowing all scripts on all sites to run unchecked. You should define custom rules for your particular use case.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I'm using IE11

Comment: @War10ck but why work fine into my web space? Demo [here](http://www.cadetill.com/heatmap.html) and I need to do security changes if it is a local file? Thanks

Comment: If your webspace is a trusted host, then it's not triggering a security warning.

Comment: @cadetill: IE will show this message by default for every webpage that includes script-code when you try to run this page from local filesystem. It's not related to any google-API, not even a simple JS-alert will work.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8765306/459897 for a way to allow scripting on filesystem for a particular page without changing permissions.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I have added the first line and chanage to CRLF endings, saving in UTF8, but still not working...