# How to avoid IE message bar when page contains JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, activex

I am trying to insert following code to all my pages:

```
<script language="javascript">
    if (top.location == self.location)
    {
        top.location = '../index.html'
    }
</script>
```

When I have this page and try to run the page from IE 8 then I am being displayed a yellow bar on top of my page which asking me to allow the plugin.

No other browser (firefox/opera/chrome/safari) does this.

This is annoying to click this every time person visits page. How to disable this?

I just hope I won't have to use:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<script language="javascript">
    if (top.location == self.location)
    {
        top.location = '../index.html'
    }
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about local execution of javascript, so see the answer in this discussion about Mark of the web (MOTW):  [ActiveX Content in a local web page, and "the mark of the web"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717596/activex-content-in-a-local-web-page-and-the-mark-of-the-web)

see also [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for futher information:

Comment: Yes, this I am opening the page locally. Will this happen from the Web?

Comment: No. this warning is usually raised only on local execution (but of course it may depend on user specific settings)

Comment: Ah! This explains everything. Thanks!